# If $a.b.c$ are consecutive positive integers and $b$ is not divisible by 2, then $c^c-a^a$ is divisible by $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I let $a=2k, b=2k+1, c=2k+2, k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Then I get $c^c-a^a=(b+1)^{2k+2}-(b-1)^{2k}=\sum_{m=0}^{2k+2}b^m-\sum_{n=0}^{2k}b^n(-1)^{2k-n}$

The items that $m,n\neq0$ are divisible by $b$

And $b^0-b^0(-1)^{2k}=0$

So $c^c-a^a$ is divisible by $b$

But I think it is so trouble, maybe there is an easy way to prove it.

Comment: I think your attempt is not so trouble, only as much trouble as $$a\equiv -1\pmod b\\ \implies a^{2k} \equiv (-1)^{2k}\equiv 1^k \equiv 1 \pmod b$$ and similarly $c^c \equiv 1\pmod b$.

Comment: And if $b$ _is_ even, then $c^c+a^a$ is divisible by $b$.

Comment: Also (back to $b$ being odd) it seems that $c^c-a^a$ is divisible by $b^2$. (And with $b$ even,  $c^c+a^a$ is divisible by $b^2$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The equation $$c \equiv 1 \pmod b$$ holds. Thus so does the equation $$c^c \equiv 1 \pmod b.$$

Likewise, the equation
$$a \equiv -1 \pmod b$$ holds, but as $a$ is even [make sure you see why], the equation $$a^a \equiv 1 \pmod b.$$

Can you finish from this.

Comment: That's right! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since $b$ is odd, let $a = 2n, b = 2n+1, c = 2n+2$.

$$
c^c - a^a = (2n+2)^{2n+2} - (2n)^{2n} \equiv 1^{2n+2} - (-1)^{2n} \equiv 0 \pmod {2n+1}
$$

Comment: Do you mean mod $2n+1$?

Comment: @2'59'2 Opps it was a typpo. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

A stronger claim that holds true is that $2^ab^2$ divides $c^c-a^a$.

- $b$ is odd, so both $a,c$ are even. So $2^a$ divides $a^a$ and $c^a$, which in turn divides $c^c$. So $2^a$ divides $c^c-a^a$.
- We have that $$\begin{align}c^c-a^a&=(b+1)^{b+1}-(b-1)^{b-1}\\&=\left(\cdots+\binom{b+1}{2}b^2+\binom{b+1}{1}b+1\right)-\left(\cdots+\binom{b-1}{2}b^2-\binom{b-1}{1}b+1\right)\\&\equiv((b+1)b+1)-(-(b-1)b+1)\mod b^2\\
  &\equiv(b+1)-(b+1)\mod b^2\\&\equiv0\mod b^2
  \end{align}$$
  So $b^2$ also divides $c^c-a^a$.

Since $b$ is odd, the LCM of $2^a$ and $b^2$ is just their product, and so $2^ab^2$ divides $c^c-a^a$.

A similar argument shows that when $b$ is even, then $b^2$ divides $c^c+a^a$.